# I want to change color to Red when updating status as Re-order level in laravel 8. how i do that?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

This is productObserver.

```
public function updating(product $product)
  {
   
   if ($product->Qty <= $product->ReOrderLevel){
      $product->Status='Reorder level';}

   else if ($product->Qty >$product->ReOrderLevel ){
      $product->Status='In Stock';}  

   if ($product->Qty <= 0) {
      $product->Status = 'Out of Stock';}
  
  }
```

This is product view. It displays all details of the product and the Status of the product. Here, I want to display status in red colour when status changes into re-order level.

```
<table>
            <tr >
              <th >@sortablelink('Name')</th>
              <th >Product View</th>
              <th >Brand</th>
              <th >@sortablelink('Price')</th>
              <th >@sortablelink('Qty')</th>
              <th>Stock_Defective</th>
              <th >Status</th>
              <th >Action</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($products as $product)
            <tr>                                                
              <td>{{$product['Name']}}</td>
              <td> <img src="{{asset('uploads/product/'.$product->image)  }}"
              class="img-circle" width="100px;" height="100px;" alt="Product-Image">  </td>
              <td>{{$product['Brand']}}</td>
              <td>{{$product['Price']}}</td>
              <td>{{$product['Qty']}}</td>
              <td>{{$product->stock_defective}}</td>
              <td>{{$product['Status']}}</td>
     
            </tr>
                @endforeach
          </table>
```

```
How I change text colour to red when updating product status as Reorder level ?
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you post what you have tried so far to get things done ? and don't post unnecessary code  it's hard to find the solution

Comment: @KamleshPaul I remove unnecessary details. can you find a solution for this?

Comment: pls check i posted my answer

Comment: Your Welcome :D ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add inline style with condition

in blade

```php
<td @if($product['Status'] =='Reorder level')  style="color: red;" @endif>{{$product['Status']}}</td>
```

use `@if($product['Status'] =='Reorder level')  style="color: red;" @endif`

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator will do the job at laravel blade.

yourfile.blade.php

```
<p class="{{ $product->Status == 'Reorder level' ? 'red' : '' }}"> some text </p>
```

your.css

```
.red { color: red }
```